# Ruby GPX file parser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gpx

Advise what can parse GPX file in Ruby?

I tried [gpx](http://github.com/dougfales/gpx), but it does not work with Ruby Enterprise Edition (https://github.com/dougfales/gpx/issues/1).

I would not like to write a parser.

Answer (score 13):

I was looking for the same thing but in the end a GPX file is just another XML file so you can parse it with XML parsing libraries like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/). Here is how I extract all the latitudes and longitudes form a GPX log:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(my-log.gpx))
trackpoints = doc.xpath('//xmlns:trkpt')
points = Array.new
trackpoints.each do |trkpt|
  points << [trkpt.xpath('@lat').to_s.to_f, trkpt.xpath('@lon').to_s.to_f]
end
```

There are probably better ways to do this but this works for me.

Comment: It should be `trackpoints = doc.xpath('//xmlns:trkpt')` (remove the last `/`)

Comment: Also, just a nit, but you can map over a Nokogiri Nodeset just like any other Enumerable:
`points = trackpoints.map { |trkpt| [trkpt.xpath('@lat').to_s.to_f, trkpt.xpath('@lon').to_s.to_f] }`

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't that familiar with using GPX and Nokogiri, and my GPX file only has a lot of `<wpt>` instead of `<trkpt>`, and this works for me:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("my_route.gpx"))

trackpoints = doc.xpath('//wpt')
points = Array.new
trackpoints.each do |trkpt|
  points << [trkpt.xpath('@lat').to_s.to_f, trkpt.xpath('@lon').to_s.to_f]
end

p points
```

Or this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("my_route.gpx"))

waypoints = doc.xpath('//wpt')
points = waypoints.map{|wpt| [wpt.xpath('@lat').to_s.to_f, wpt.xpath('@lon').to_s.to_f]}

p points
```